# Trying to have my controller continuously fire every 60 seconds. (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server-sent-events, actioncable

I'm building a ticker app that will alert users based on data that will refresh every 60 seconds. I don't want the new calls for data to come from the client but don't know how to get the controller to continuously make its API call and push to the client.

```
 def search
    @price = find_price()
    render json: @price
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    # def setprice
    #   @price = Price.find(params[:id])
    # end

    def request_api()
      response = Excon.get(
        'example.api'
      )

      return nil if response.status != 200
    data = JSON.parse(response.body)
    data['PriceRange']['4']
    end

    def find_price()
      request_api()
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def price_params
      params.require(:price).permit(:price)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't do it through the controller, because once the controller processes the client's request, it "forgets" about the client. What you want is some kind of [ActionCable](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html) solution. ActionCable is Rails' way of setting up websockets; if you have a websocket connection the server can push updates to each client that's connected to it.